# C - My program keep fork non stop, crash my terminal

Tags: c

My terminal keep create and forking . I think i did something wrong in my code, i actually want fork when client connect, but when i launch the server, its sort of keep forking as i check with linux command "ps" ,how do i change my code to make it work properly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>


using namespace std;

int main()
{

int serverFd;
int clientFd;
int serverLen;
int clientLen;
string message;
string serverSockAddrPtr;
struct sockaddr* serverSockAddressPnt;
struct sockaddr* clientSockAddressPnt;
struct sockaddr_un serverAddress;
struct sockaddr_un clientAddress;


// SOCKET CREATION PART - SERVER
serverFd = socket (AF_LOCAL, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

/* Set domain type */
serverAddress.sun_family = AF_LOCAL; 

/* Set name */ 
strcpy (serverAddress.sun_path, "CountryServer"); 


/* GET SIZE OF Server Addres */
serverLen = sizeof serverAddress;
/* GET SIZE OF Client Addres */
clientLen = sizeof clientAddress;

/* Get Server Sock Address Pointer*/
serverSockAddressPnt = (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddress; 
/* Get Client Sock Address Pointer*/
clientSockAddressPnt = (struct sockaddr *) &clientAddress; 

/* Create file */
bind (serverFd, serverSockAddressPnt , serverLen);

/* listen for connection */
listen (serverFd,5);

// SOCKET CREATION END - SERVER


while(1)
{
//accept client connection
clientFd = accept(serverFd, clientSockAddressPnt, (socklen_t*)&clientLen);

if(fork()==0)
{
message="Successfully connected to the server";
write(clientFd,message.c_str(),strlen(message.c_str())+1);
close(clientFd);
exit(0);
}
else
close(clientFd);

}

return 0;
}
```

My question is:
How do i make the server to fork a process to handle client query when they connect.

I don't want it keep forking for no reasons.
Thanks for all help, this my first C coding to learn more about programming.

My client and server communicate through localhost, sockaddr_un and not internet.

Comment: Sounds like you fork-bombed yourself?

Comment: Yes i did, how do i fix it haha, i am new to C programing

Comment: @Mysticial: not a fork-bomb, which would crash the machine, just continuous forking of a (one-at-a-time) child because the return value of `accept` isn't checked for errors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you should have for your loop is:

```
while (1) {
    clientFd = accept(serverFd, clientSockAddressPnt, (socklen_t*)&clientlen);
    if (clientFd >= 0) {
        if(fork() == 0) {
            message="Successfully connected to the server";
            write(clientFd,message.c_str(),strlen(message.c_str())+1);
            close(clientFd);
            exit(0);
        }
        else
            close(clientFd);
    }
}
```

That way, you only ever fork when accept returns a nonnegative value (which means it completed successfully.

Comment: How do I make the program to fork when client connect, rather than keep forking.

Comment: I am doing localhost connection, sockaddr_un only , not internet

Comment: Wrap your if/else block with an if statement to ensure that you only execute it if you connect. If I recall correctly, accept returns a nonnegative integer on success, so you probably want `if (clientFd >= 0)`

Answer (score 4):

You should check the return value from `accept()`. You are getting an error, which you should fix.

The reason it keeps calling fork() is because every time you go around the loop, accept() returns (really quickly!) with an error instead of waiting for a new connection.

Comment: How should i proceed with the checking. and ensure it won't keep fork, and only fork to handle client when they connected. and do nothing(not forking) when no client connect